# Multi language apps into one - best strategy

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, multilingual, maintainability

I created a mobile game for kids several years ago. I did 10 language versions. Each exists as a different app in Apple and Google Play. Now Apple rejects one of the upgrades - they say it is spam. OK, I build a new release with all 10 languages in one app. I was thinking about this because it takes a lot of time to maintain 10 apps per store. And now I am wondering about strategy: upload it as an upgrade of the one existing language app (this with the best results in the past) or create a completely new app both in Apple and Google Play (and lost app history: reviews, download counter). And delete the rest of the apps. What do you think?

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Comment: I made it as an update for the most downloaded app (as you said - and it was my own thought also). But the result in Google Play is I can not find my app when I search the main keyword (it was at the top a few days ago)!

Comment: Good to know. and regarding the searchability, this will need some time. (usually around 1 week after full roll-out)

Answer (score 0):

Make it as an update for the most downloaded app from your collection.
remember to make a separate store listing for each language.